# How to fix the position of align environment

Tags: align, positioning

Here is a quick question regarding the position of `align` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

%%%  lots of text here.

\begin{align*}
& \mathcal{A}(Q \rightarrow Q^{*},P) = min(1, \dfrac{p(Q^{*};P)}{p(Q;P)}\dfrac{q(Q | Q^{*})}{q(Q^{*} | Q)}) \\
& = min(1, exp(\alpha \cdot (\Delta(Q^{*},P) - \Delta(Q;P)))\cdot \dfrac{q(Q | Q^{*})}{q(Q^{*} | Q)})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I am using the above `align` environment to define a formula. However, the problem is that I just cannot fix the position of this formula. Indeed it floats to the top of the text and affects the readability a lot. Could any one shed some lights on how to fix this environment? Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a complete self contain example. Your example above does not even compile. You can also add some text that shows the problem.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *fixing the position*? Maths environments never float. Maybe, it should appear naturally at the bottom of the page, but there's not enough room left for both rows, and you didn't add the  `\allowdisplaybreaks` directive in your preamble, so it goes to the top of the next page?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it floats to the top of the tex". E.g., does it get placed at the top of the next page?

Comment: A problem might be a blank line before `\begin{align*}`, which should never be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "[the `align` environment] floats to the top of the text". For sure, display math environments in LaTeX do not "float", where the "float" is a LaTeX-specific term. (In LaTeX, the two main "floating" environments are `figure` and `table`.) If you wish to allow a page break *inside* an `align` environment, simply issue the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` (in the preamble, *after* loading the `amsmath` package.

Since you care about the readability of your paper, you should also try to improve the look of the equation, say by (a) using upright lettering for "min" and "exp", (b) using `\mid` instead of `|` to denote conditioning, (c) using large parentheses where appropriate, and (d) alternating between round parentheses and square brackets. Also, it seems more natural to align the two rows on the `=` symbol than typesetting them flush-left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

%%%  lots of text here.

\noindent\textcolor{red}{before}
\begin{align*}
& \mathcal{A}(Q \rightarrow Q^{*},P) = min(1, \dfrac{p(Q^{*};P)}{p(Q;P)}\dfrac{q(Q | Q^{*})}{q(Q^{*} | Q)}) \\
& = min(1, exp(\alpha \cdot (\Delta(Q^{*},P) - \Delta(Q;P)))\cdot \dfrac{q(Q | Q^{*})}{q(Q^{*} | Q)})
\end{align*}

\noindent\textcolor{red}{after}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{A}(Q \rightarrow Q^{*},P) 
&= \min\biggl(1, \frac{p(Q^{*};P)}{p(Q;P)}\frac{q(Q \mid Q^{*})}{q(Q^{*} \mid Q)}\biggr) \\
&= \min\biggl(1, \exp\bigl(\alpha \cdot [\Delta(Q^{*},P) - \Delta(Q;P)]\bigr)\times 
\frac{q(Q \mid Q^{*})}{q(Q^{*} \mid Q)}\biggr)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```